# How to merge two integer arrays in ascending order?

Tags: java, arrays, merge

How can I merge two arrays in ascending order?
I have the code below and I need to merge this array in ascending order, and it should be in a separate method. So in this case the method should return `{1, 4, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13}`

```
public class MergingArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1 = {4, 8, 12, 13};
        int [] array2 = {1, 9, 11};
        merge(array1, array2);
    } 
    public static int[] merge(int array1[], int array2[]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The most obvious way would be to repetitively search for the minimum of both arrays until both arrays are empty.

Comment: `return Stream.of(array1, array2).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sorted().toArray();`

Comment: Your problem isn't well defined. You haven't said how duplicate integer values are to be handled.  Are only distinct values present in the result?  Are the input arrays always sorted in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking to merge two sorted arrays, you could do it like this.

```
public static int[] merge(int array1[], int array2[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int size1 = array1.length;
    int size2 = array2.length;
    int[] result = new int[size1 + size2];

    while (i < size1 && j < size2) {
        if (array1[i] < array2[j]) {
            result[k++] = array1[i++];
        } else {
            result[k++] = array2[j++];
        }
    }

    // Store remaining elements
    while (i < size1) {
        result[k++] = array1[i++];
    }

    while (j < size2) {
        result[k++] = array2[j++];
    }
    
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] merge(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int totalElements = array1.length + array2.length, array2Index = 0;
        int[] toReturn = new int[totalElements];

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            toReturn[i] = array1[i];
        }
        for (int i = array1.length; i < totalElements; i++) {
            toReturn[i] = array2[array2Index++];
        }

        //Manual Ascending Array Sorting
        for (int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalElements; j++) {
                if(toReturn[i] < toReturn[j]) {
                    int temp = toReturn[i];
                    toReturn[i] = toReturn[j];
                    toReturn[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons class and the sort function of Collections class

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MergingArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1 = {4, 8, 12, 13};
        int [] array2 = {1, 9, 11};
        merge(array1, array2);
    } 
    public static int[] merge(int array1[], int array2[]) {
    return Collections.sort(ArrayUtils.addAll(array1, array2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar task on interview. The main logic is to compare each element in both arrays until one ends. And then just append the rest of the numbers.

```
static int[] geMergedArrayC(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {

        // Count the length
        int lengthA = arrayA.length;
        int lengthB = arrayB.length;
        int lengthC = lengthA + lengthB;
        int[] arrayC = new int[lengthC];
        
        // Cursors to keep the position
        int cursorA = 0;
        int cursorB = 0;
        int cursorC = 0;
        
        // Store the temp values
        int aValue;
        int bValue;

        for (; cursorC < lengthC; cursorC++) {
            // Add from both arrays until one ends
            if (cursorA < lengthA && cursorB < lengthB) {
                aValue = arrayA[cursorA];
                bValue = arrayB[cursorB];
                if (aValue <= bValue) {
                    // Add from array A
                    arrayC[cursorC] = aValue;
                    cursorA++;
                } else {
                    // Add from array B
                    arrayC[cursorC] = bValue;
                    cursorB++;
                }

            } else if (cursorA < lengthA) {
                // Add from array A
                aValue = arrayA[cursorA];
                arrayC[cursorC] = aValue;
                cursorA++;

            } else {
                // Add from array B
                bValue = arrayB[cursorB];
                arrayC[cursorC] = bValue;
                cursorB++;
            }
        }

        return arrayC;
    }
```